# SQL Server select date year/month portion only without day and with comparison

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, select

I have a list in a table with a `StartDate (not null)` and an `EndDate (null)` (both of type `date` without time).

An active entry is one with `StartDate <= querydate` and `EndDate with null or > querydate`.

So my query would basically be like

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyDataTable 
WHERE StartDate <= mydate 
  AND (EndDate IS NULL OR EndDate >= mydate )
```

For a statistic in a diagram, I want to know which ones are active in a specific month for the last months. I loop (programatically) over the year and month (2017-10, 2017-11, 2017-12, 2018-1, ... )

How can I select all active entries using year and month of the program loop but ignoring the day part?

Comment: In the future, don't describe your tables and data. Show the table definition, provide sample data, and give an example of the output. It makes it much easier to understand.

Comment: If you are doing it progamatically then you can extract the month and year from `myDate`. So let's say if `myDate` has 10 month and year 2017  then modify the query as `SELECT * FROM MyDataTble Where Month(date)='10' && YEAR(date)='2017` and do the comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want actives for the entire month:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyDataTable
WHERE StartDate <= '2017-10-01' AND 
      (EndDate IS NULL OR EndDate >= '2017-11-01');
```

If you want actives at any time during the month:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyDataTable
WHERE StartDate < '2017-11-01' AND 
      (EndDate IS NULL OR EndDate > '2017-10-01');
```

Comment: I though more of a build in date function which targets only the year and month part but that will do the job too. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this by using only months by using '[DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms189794(v=sql.120).aspx)':

```
DECLARE @startDate DATE = '2017-11-01';
DECLARE @numberOfMonth INT;

SELECT @numberOfMonth = datediff(month, @startDate, GETDATE());


SELECT * 
FROM MyDataTable 
WHERE datediff(month, StartDate, GETDATE()) >= @numberOfMonth
AND (EndDate IS NULL OR datediff(month, EndDate, GETDATE()) <= 
@numberOfMonth)
```